# How do I raise my friendship level with everyone?

Tags: rune-factory-4

Apparently Eliza wants me to raise my friendship level with everyone in the village (I think). A lot of people in town are at 1, but a bunch are at zero, and I can't really figure out how to increase it.

Can I do it just by talking to people? Or do I have to find gifts for everyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is just to talk with them everyday. Its not worth much, but it's reliable. You can also give them home cooked foods. You'll get a pretty decent chunk of friendship from that, and I have yet to meet anyone not like any random food I made.

Comment: That's just good advice in general. People like it when you talk to them and offer them food . . . Oh, wait, we're talking about a game!

Comment: I dunno; jamming it down their throat sounds more like scariness than being nice...

Comment: Well, I figured for a site comprising mostly gamer types, any social advice, even mildly creepy, would be helpful . . .

Comment: Other ways to raise relationship are taking the person with you in combat (requires a base relationship level though), and winning festivals.